# Integral of the product $x^n e^x$

Tags: calculus, integration

I would be very pleased if you could give me your opinion about this way of integrating the following expression. I think that it has no issues, but just wanted to confirm:

$$ \int x^n e^x dx $$
$$ e^x = u $$
$$ e^x dx = du $$
$$ \int x^n e^x dx = \int \ln(u)^n du = nu(\ln(u) - 1) + C $$
$$ \int x^n e^xdx = ne^x (x-1) + C $$

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another variation is using the *[Differential operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator)* $D_x$ and it's inverse $D_x^{-1}$ denoting indefinite integration.

> The  following is valid
>   \begin{align*}
> D_x^{-1}\left(e^xf(x)\right)=e^x\frac{1}{1+D_x}f(x) \tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> We obtain with (1)
>   \begin{align*}
> \int e^x x^n\, dx&=\frac{1}{D_x}\left(e^x x^n\right)\\
> &=e^x\frac{1}{1+D_x}x^n\\
> &=e^x\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^kD_x^k x^n\tag{2}\\
> &=e^x\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\frac{n!}{k!}x^{n-k}
> \end{align*}

*Comment*

- In (2) we use the  *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*.

Comment: @MarioMadrid: You're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 2):

No, your argument is completely wrong, sorry. You are mistaking
$$
(\ln u)^n
$$
with
$$
\ln(u^n)
$$
which are very different.

By the way, if you try differentiating, you get
$$
D(ne^x(x-1))=ne^x(x-1)+ne^x=nxe^x
$$

---

Hint:
$$
\int x^ne^x\,dx=(x^n+p(x))e^x
$$
where $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n-1$.

Comment: Many thanks! This community is great help.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int (\ln u)^n \, \mathrm{d}u \neq nu (\ln u - 1) + C$$

Indeed, the way to go about this is to use IBP and get a recurrence relation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to proceed.  Note that

$$\begin{align}
\int x^ne^x\,dx&=\left.\left(\frac{d^n}{da^n}\int e^{ax}\,dx\right)\right|_{a=1}\\\\
&=\left.\left(\frac{d^n}{da^n}\frac{e^{ax}}{a}\right)\right|_{a=1}\\\\
&=\left.\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{d^k a^{-1}}{da^k}\frac{d^{n-k} e^{ax}}{da^{n-k}}\right)\right|_{a=1}\\\\
&=e^x\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \left(\binom{n}{k}\,k!\right)x^{n-k}\\\\
&=e^x\left(x^n+\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^n\left(n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots (n-k+1)\right)x^{n-k}\right)
\end{align}$$

which gives the explicit form of the polynomial, $p(x)$, as discussed in the post by egreg.

Comment: Great way to go, thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure. -Mark

Comment: Why was the best vote changed??

Answer (score 1):

If you have an integral of the form $$\int f(x)g(x)dx$$ such that $\exists\ n \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $$\frac{d^nf(x)}{dx^n}=0$$ 
And the repeated integral of $g(x)$ is easy to compute (as is the case for exponentials), it is convenient to apply the [Tabular Method for integration by parts](http://pages.pacificcoast.net/~cazelais/187/tabular.pdf) and then proceed by induction.