# Estimation for $a_n$ where $\int_0^1 x^ne^xdx = a_ne+b_n$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, estimation

\begin{align}
I_n=\int_0^1 x^ne^xdx = a_ne+b_n 
\end{align}
where $a_n,b_n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n\geq0$ is a integer.

How to find a bound for $a_n$ in the form $a_n<f(n) \: ?$

I'm not sure what are the most appropriate tags for this question.

Using Taylor series for $e^x$, $\int_0^1 x^ne^xdx = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!(n+k+1)}$. Maybe evaluating this series would help?

To give a example of what I'm asking:

\begin{align}
&I_0=e-1\\
&I_1= 1\\
&I_2= e-2\\
&I_3=6-2e\\
&I_4=9e-24\\
\end{align}

Above, the number $a_n$ that multiplies $e$ is of the form $|a_n|<n^2$, if $n\leq4$. I'm looking for a estimation that is valid for all $n\geq0$.

Comment: Do such $a_n$ and $b_n$ always exist?

Comment: If $n\geq0$ and integer, yes.

Comment: Does [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int(x%5En*e%5Ex,x%3D0..1)) answer your question?

Comment: From Servaes's comment, we have $a_n=(-1)^n (!n)=(-1)^n\left[\frac{n!}{e}\right]\approx \frac{(-1)^n n!}{e}$ and $b_n=(-1)^{n-1}n!$.  Here, $[x]$ is the integer closest to an irrational number $x$.

Comment: $n!$ seems like a very bad estimation though.

Comment: It is not $n!$.  I typed in $!n$.  This is the [subfactorial function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subfactorial.html).  And $!n$ grows much faster than $n^2$.

Comment: But what about $a_n \approx \frac{(-1)^nn!}{e}$ ?

Comment: Did you even read the link I put there?

Comment: Consider the exponential generating function $S(t) \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^n I_n}{n!}$. We have $S(t)= \frac{e^{t+1}-1}{t+1}$ and $\frac{d^n}{dt^n}S(t) \vert_{t=0}= I_n ,$ so solving this for $a_n$ and $b_n$ gives $a_n= (-1)^nn! \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$ and $b_n=(-1)^{n+1}n!.$ In particular $|a_n| < Cn! e^{-1}$ for $n$ large. Don't know if that helps.

Comment: Although this question is already answered, I'd like to connect to some existing posts: one [less relevant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862264), and one [closely related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2198161).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \int_{0}^{1} f(x) e^{x}\,dx = \left[\left(f(x)-f'(x)+f''(x)-f'''(x)+\ldots\right)e^x\right]_{0}^{1}$$
gives that, up to the sign, $b_n$ is the number of elements of $S_n$ (i.e. n!) and $a_n$ is the number of permutations without fixed points (derangements) in $S_n$. Of course the signs of $a_n$ and $b_n$ are always opposite since

$$ \int_{0}^{1} x^n e^{x}\,dx \sim \int_{0}^{1} x^n(1+(e-1)x)\,dx \sim \frac{e}{n} $$
as $n\to +\infty$, so $|a_n|\sim\frac{n!}{e}$. A marvelous strategy for finding accurate rational approximations of $e$ (actually the convergents of its continued fraction) is to consider the similar (Beuker-like) integrals

$$\int_{0}^{1}x^n(1-x)^n e^{x}\,dx < \frac{e}{4^n}.$$